# Laravel 4: Extend model's query to return additional fields with a model (no relations) but don't write data to attributes property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Suppose, I have some model-related data in several tables, other than the model resides it. Those tables are dynamically created (custom EAV implementation). How do I make Eloquent join those tables on queries it uses to fetch models without building a relation?

It would be good if I could hack into a query that Eloquent is going to use to return models from database after the query is fully constructed, but before it is executed.

Also, the problem is that data from joined tables should not go to model's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to add additional attributes in a model dynamically when querying the database using `Eloquent` and it won't be included with the model's attributes for example, if you want to add a field in the model which is not available in the model's attributes property but you want to use it like an attribute, then just create an `accessor` method in the model like this:

```
// In User model for example
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

Now, if you use something like this:

```
echo User::find(1)->fullName;
```

Then you'll get a full name string (Concatenated `first_name` and `last_name`) printed but actually there is no `fullName` field available as the model's `attribute`. This is called an `accessor` method and check the documentation for this ([Accessors & Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)) on `Laravel` website.

Comment: I need to query data for this attribute from DB (not from model's native table,  but from some other using JOIN with model's original fetch query). This is impossible with accessors. They just access, not query data from DB.

Comment: Then you need to join tables using `DB::table('tableName')->join(...)` or `Model::join(...)`.

Comment: sure, but how to do that while fetching model from DB? How do I hack into that fetching query?

Comment: Provide your relation of tables to each other, the database tables fields structure.

Comment: Relations are dynamic and can be created on the fly by application user.

Comment: What does even that mean ? How do you join two tables without having a relation using a foreign key ?